# How to use shift+alt+arrow-down for copy the selected lines just under the selected lines in Visual Studio Code

Tags: html, css, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

Previously I used Windows 10 operating system. I am a beginner and I am learning HTML, CSS. I used Visual Studio Code on Windows 10. There I used the <kbd>shift + alt + arrow-down</kbd> key to duplicate some selected lines just under the selected lines. I recently shifted to Ubuntu and the <kbd>shift + alt + arrow-down</kbd> key is not working like windows. It is not duplicating the selected lines.

How can I make these keys working like windows or is there any other key to do the same work?

Help me, please.

Comment: Try Ctrl + Shift + Alt + Up/Down.
[ https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-linux.pdf ]

Comment: This method is not working. It is creating new workspace.

Answer (score 11):

**For Linux:**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>  and  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>

You Might need to use numpad Down and Up for Linux

You can also go to: **File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts.** and search for: **Copy Line Down** or **Copy Line Up**, change the keyboard shortcut for this command by right clicking on the command and selecting **Change Keybinding**

Comment: This answer fixes my similar problem. Using the Number Pad's Up and Down Arrow keys fixes the broken Shift+Alt+Up/Down Arrow when it stopped working for me after updating from 17.2.4 to with Visual Studio 2022 17.2.5 in Windows 11.

Answer (score 3):

Install the "Windows default keybindings" extension

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu, you can use this combination to **Copy Line Down** and **Copy Line Up** *Ctrl + Shift + D* and **Ctrl + Shift + Alt + UpArrow** respectively. You can can also update these keys to your preferred keys as hinted by @Syed Muhammad Moiz

Answer (score -1):

On windows you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to Copy Line Down.